# probability distribution of topics using NMF

Tags: scikit-learn, topic-modeling, nmf

I use the following code to do the topic modeling on my documents:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, max_df=0.85, min_df=3, ngram_range=(1,5))

tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)
tfidf_feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()


from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

no_topics = 50

%time nmf = NMF(n_components=no_topics, random_state=11,  init='nndsvd').fit(tfidf)
topic_pr= nmf.transform(tfidf)
```

I thought topic_pr gives me the probability distribution of different topics for each document. In other words, I expected that the numbers in the output(topic_pr) would be probabilities that the document in row X belongs to each of the 50 topics in model. But, the numbers do not add to 1. Are these really probabilities? If no, is there a way to convert them to probabilities?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

NMF returns a non-negative factorization, doesn't have anything to do with probabilities (to the best of my knowledge). If you just want probabilities you could transform the output of NMF (L1 normalization)

```
probs = topic_pr / topic_pr.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

This assumes that `topic_pr` is a non-negative matrix, which is true in your case.

---

EDIT: Apparently there is a probabilistic version of NMF.

Quoting [sklearn's documetation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-topics-extraction-with-nmf-lda-py):

> Non-negative Matrix Factorization is applied with two different objective functions: the Frobenius norm, and the generalized Kullback-Leibler divergence. The latter is equivalent to Probabilistic Latent Semantic Indexing.

To apply the latter, which is what you seem to need, from the same link:

```
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=no_topics, max_iter=5)
topic_pr = lda.fit_transform(tfidf)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried `code` nmf = NMF(n_components=no_topics, random_state=1, beta_loss='kullback-leibler', solver='mu', alpha=.1, l1_ratio=.5).fit(tfidf) but still the outcomes don't add up to 1. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Did you try using the last two lines of my answer instead of NMF?